How to locate mysql-connector-java and add it to classpath
I have the following Jenkins versions and plugins:
Jenkins 2.426.3

database:247.v244b_d85f086d
database-mysql:63.va_0596d2b_1438
mysql-api:8.4.0-31.va_b_5ce7933762

And here is my code to connect to mysql db:
Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver")

def url = 'jdbc:mysql://<host>:<port>/<db>'
def driver = 'com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver'
def sql = Sql.newInstance(url, "${username}", "${password}", driver)

It fails with No suitable driver found.
From all the questions/answers I was reading on stackoverflow I think the reason to the failure is that mysql-connector-java driver is not in the CLASSPATH.
One of the answers suggested finding classpath from Jenkins Script Console and here is what I found:
System.getProperty("java.class.path")
Result: /usr/lib/jenkins/jenkins.war

From my understanding, jar files are packed inside jenkins.war.
I checked what's in /var/lib/jenkins/war/WEB-INF/lib and there is no mysql-connector-java driver (.jar file).
I was able to find mysql-connector-j-8.4.0.jar under /var/lib/jenkins/plugins/mysql-api/WEB-INF/lib/
and
database-mysql.jar under /var/lib/jenkins/plugins/database-mysql/WEB-INF/lib/
Where do I need to copy these jars to get rid of No suitable driver found and connect to mysql?

do you have one main jenkins node or multiple nodes/workers?

@daggett it looks like just one node. Sorry I am not very proficient in Jenkins

Have you tried using the database-mysql-plugin provided wrapper? See their tests, for example:
import org.jenkinsci.plugins.database.mysql.MySQLDatabase

MySQLDatabase database = new MySQLDatabase(
    'foo.com:3306',
    'database-name',
    'user',
    'password',
    null)


Hi, thanks for the suggestion. I get the following error unable to resolve class org.jenkinsci.plugins.database.mysql.MySQLDatabase

Have you restarted Jenkins after installing the plugin?

yes, multiple times

Answering my own question as I found what works.
Please note: I did not have to download the mysql driver manually because I have the mysql plugins installed

Find where mysql driver jar file is located
I checked the following directories



/var/lib/jenkins/plugins/database-mysql/WEB-INF/lib/ and it only contained database-mysql.jar
/var/lib/jenkins/plugins/mysql-api/WEB-INF/lib/ and it contained mysql-connector-j-8.4.0.jar.


Verify that jenkins classpath does not contain the mysql driver
I checked /var/lib/jenkins/war/WEB-INF/lib (the direcory where all jar files are stored) and there were no mysql driver.

Copy mysql driver to jenkins classpath
cp /var/lib/jenkins/plugins/mysql-api/WEB-INF/lib/mysql-connector-j-8.4.0.jar /var/lib/jenkins/war/WEB-INF/lib

Restart jenkins
https://<your_jenkins_url>.com/restart


